# Fast counting semaphore on Windows?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, synchronization, semaphore

First of all, I know that it can be implemented with a mutex and condition variable, but I want the most efficient implementation possible.
I would like a semaphore with a fast-path when there's no contention. On Linux this is easy with a futex; for example, here's a wait:

```
if (AtomicDecremenIfPositive(_counter) > 0) return; // Uncontended
AtomicAdd(&_waiters, 1);
do
{
    if (syscall(SYS_futex, &_counter, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, nullptr, nullptr, 0) == -1) // Sleep
    {
        AtomicAdd(&_waiters, -1);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to wait for futex");
    }
}
while (AtomicDecrementIfPositive(_counter) <= 0);
AtomicAdd(&_waiters, -1);
```

and post:

```
AtomicAdd(&_counter, 1);
if (Load(_waiters) > 0 && syscall(SYS_futex, &_counter, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1, nullptr, nullptr, 0) == -1) throw std::runtime_error("Failed to wake futex"); // Wake one
```

At first I thought for Windows to just use NtWaitForKeyedEvent(). The problem is it's not a direct substitution because it doesn't atomically check the value at _counter before going into the kernel, and so can miss the wake from NtReleaseKeyedEvent(). Worse, then NtReleaseKeyedEvent() would block.
What's the best solution?

Comment: A semaphore restricts the number of concurrent access to a shared resource. A mutex serializes access so that concurrent users must wait. Which do you want?

Comment: Semaphores. Mutexes are supposed to be unlocked by the thread that locked them. I need threads waiting on semaphores that others will post.

Comment: Hmm.. first thoughts:  if the semaphore count is represented by an integer, an atomic decrement on the sema that results in a negative number indicates that the caller needs to wait.  An atomic increment on the sema that results in zero or a negative result indicates that there is a waiting thread that needs to be released.  Would this, together with one of your 'super-CS' to protect lists of events for threads to wait on, make a better semaphore with a faster 'no kernel' path for some cases?

Comment: Oh.. are you using the semaphore for communication with drivers, ie. restricted system calls anyway, or just for inter-thread comms in user-space?

Comment: Note that `NTReleaseKeyedEvent` blocks so you _cannot_ miss a wake. That's the intent behind it. Keyed events have a much bigger problem though insofar as they are even less documented than the abysmally documented futexes (i.e. not at all). When I tried to implement the exact same thing you're attempting now a few weeks ago, I had `NtWaitForKeyedEvent` segfault every single time, although there truly isn't so much you could do wrong, or so you would think.

Comment: @MartinJames, one place I use semaphores is for conditional sleeping of producers in a system with a non-blocking consumer (the consumer has other stuff to do, but will use an updated result from a producer if available). Producers block themselves with a sem_wait() whenever they fill the buffer, and the consumer will sem_post() whenever it takes a new result from the buffer. In this case a binary seamphore would suffice, but I can't use a mutex because a mutex is supposed to be unlocked by the thread that owns it.

Comment: @Damon, I was thinking that's the reason they made the release call block. But I don't think that a mutex unlock, or a semaphore post, or a condvar signal should ever have the chance to block. Also, handling missed wakes this way is probably less efficient than the way it's handled in the fast mutex from locklessinc.com/articles/keyed_events/ It's unfortunate this part of the API is undocumented, but I've never had NtWaitForKeyedEvent crash.

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit weird to have a semaphore post block.  But given how the keyed events are supposed to be used, that will happen only if the waiter is *exactly* between its fastpath (CAS) and the call to NtWaitForKeyedEvent, which should be a window of only a few clock cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
// bottom 16 bits: post count
// top 16 bits: wait count
struct Semaphore { unsigned val; }

wait(struct Semaphore *s)
{
retry:
    do
        old = s->val;
        if old had posts (bottom 16 bits != 0)
            new = old - 1
            wait = false
        else
            new = old + 65536
            wait = true
    until successful CAS of &s->val from old to new

    if wait == true
        wait on keyed event
        goto retry;
}

post(struct Semaphore *s)
{
    do
        old = s->val;
        if old had waiters (top 16 bits != 0)
            // perhaps new = old - 65536 and remove the "goto retry" above?
            // not sure, but this is safer...
            new = old - 65536 + 1
            release = true
        else
            new = old + 1
            release = false
    until successful CAS of &s->val from old to new

    if release == true
        release keyed event
}
```

*edit*: that said, I'm not sure this would help you a lot.  Your thread pool usually should be big enough that a thread is always ready to process your request.  This means that not only waits, but also posts will always take the slow path and go to the kernel.  So, counting semaphores are probably the one primitive where you do not really care about a userspace-only fastpath.  Stock Win32 semaphores should be good enough.  That said, I'm happy to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Windows has native semaphores with [CreateSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Until and unless you have some kind of documented performance problem doing it the normal way, you shouldn't even consider optimizations that are fragile or hardware-specific.

Comment: I have had an order of magnitude performance gain from using the custom way for mutexes instead of Windows critical sections (and it's somewhat faster than the slim rw locks as well), and so have very reasonable expectation of a significant improvement doing the same for semaphores. The native semaphores are heavyweight kernel calls even in the uncontended case, which is quite common. An unnecessary kernel call is ~10x slower than an atomic operation that checks whether it's needed.

Comment: If you have so many calls to synchronization functions that their overhead isn't lost in the noise, you are either writing *very* low-level code or you are using synchronization functions totally inappropriately.

Comment: It's the latter. And I've no issue with being specific to x86 and x86-64, as I control the specification of the deployment machines. In any case, I'd like to get back to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for your first idea, e.g critical section and condition variable. Critical section is fast enough and it does use interlocked operation before it goes to sleep.  Or, you can experiment with  SRWLocks instead of critical section. Condition variables (and SRWLocks) are very fast - their only problem is that there are no conditions on XP, but maybe you do not need to target this platform .

Answer (score 0):

Qt has all kinds of things like QMutex, QSemaphore which are implemented in spirit like what you presented in your question.

Actually, I would suggest replacing the futex stuff with the usual OS-provided synchronization primitives; it should not matter much since that is the slow path anyway.

Comment: I should add that Qt also provides the necessary atomic operations required for building your own synchronization mechanism (compare-and-swap most prominently).